# with jquery, how would i get get all hidden input within an html table "mytable" that has class= "updatable"

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

question in subject . .

basically i see that i can do this to get all hidden elements

```
var input = $(#mytable:hidden);
```

but i can't seem to do something like this:

```
var input = $(#mytable:hidden:input.updatable);
```

is there a way to have multiple criteria in a selector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
var input = $("#mytable input.updatable:hidden");
```

Alternatively, you can specify a "context" to search within. This should have the same result as the example above, just another way to do it.

```
var table = $("#mytable");
var input = $("input.updatable:hidden", table);
```